# ALT-GR not working after internal laptop keyboard replacement

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, laptop-repair

I have replaced my Notebooks (Packard Bell P5WS0) Keyboard because the old one was not working properly anymore. After I installed the new internal Keyboard, I noticed that all keys seem to work but ALT-GR. I do not know if the key worked before the replacement, because I haven't been using the Notebook for some time.

My question is: What could likely be the error causing FN and ALT-GR keys not to work while all others (I have checked all but some F Keys) do work?

What I tested:

- I did a clean boot. Problem still there.
- I booted into safe mode (Windows 7) but the problem persists.
- ALT-GR works on Microsofts Screen Keyboard.
- I connected a Keyboard per USB, ALT-GR works.
- I don't have any remote desktop sessions open.
- Booted into Ubuntu on an USB stick. FN and ALT-GR still don't work.
- There is no special keyboard driver for this laptop model.

A few hours after Installation, and after my problem solving attempts, the FN key stopped responding, too. This persists even after reenabling all startup programs.

I have a few theories what the problem is:

Maybe the connection between motherboard and Keyboard is not 100% correct, and therefore the signal does not make it.

I could have bought the wrong keyboard. On the case it says Model No: P5WS0. I have ordered with this Identifier. The keyboard fits perfectly. However that Notebook has more Identifiers, like EasyNote TS, EasyNote TS11HR or EASYNOTE_F4211-050GE. I did not order for those. The replacement keyboard states to be compatible with TS11 models.

Or the new keyboard is simply defective.

Edit: I am not 100% sure fn keys worked ever (on the replacement keyboard). I replaced my mainboard battery which reset fn behavior to always on. I think fn+F1-12 worked after changing that bios setting back but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I have changed my question to fit the rules, yet it is still on hold. Why?